# undefined method `all' for {:conditions=>{:retailer_id=>[1, 2]}}:Hash In rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I am getting an error while fetching the data from the model, Here is the scenario I have created a "ProductSearch" Engine and inside the ProductSearch I have controllers, models, helpers, and views.

Now the controller method gives an error while executing below is the code for controller method

```
  def stores_in_mall
    @stores ||= TenantRetailigenceRetailer.
        for_property(@property).all(:include => :retailer, :order => 'retailers.name').
        reject{ |s| s.retailer.nil? || s.retailer.suite.nil? }
  end
```

Here is the code for ProductSearch Model

```
module ProductSearch
  class TenantRetailigenceRetailer < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :retailer
      belongs_to :retailigence_retailer
      attr_accessor :tenant_id, :retailigence_retailer_id
      scope :for_property, lambda{ |property|
                                 { :conditions => { :retailer_id => property.retailers.map(&:id) } }
                               }

      def name
        retailer.name
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: you are using rails 4 ?

Comment: just change scope :for_property, lambda {|property|  retailer_id: property.retailers.map(&:id)}

Comment: Yes I am using rails 4 @Thorin

Comment: I guess there is no issue with scope :for_property , Its issue with ActiveRecord because "all" method available to all models by default.

Comment: I dont think you need to add 'all' there, can you try to remove 'all' and change scope as I added in my previous comment?

Comment: Your scope is returning a hash not ActiveRecord Relation. You can use "all" method only on Model objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple scope if they return activerecord relation

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :find_someone, -> (id) { where(id: id) }
  scope :find_another, -> { where(type: "xyz")}
end
```

Now you can use them together like

```
Person.find_someone(1).find_another.all
```

But in your case the scope is returning a condition

> {:conditions=>{:retailer_id=>[1, 2]}}

So the 'all' method will not work.

Comment: Yes @Mahesh you are right , I am not getting ActiveRecord that's why all method not working..!!